# Is it possible to perform a HTTP POST from a HTML email?

Tags: email-client

If I receive an email in any email client be it Outlook, GMail, etc and the email contains a link to a website, is it possible to perform a POST request to the website as opposed to a GET request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For information *retrieval*, including links made with `<a href>`, only GET can be used.

If you want POST for whatever reason, you'll have to create a `<form method="post">` with a submit button. (And [think carefully](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html) about whether you *need* it; it's an ugly way to track users, and it's uncacheable.)

Comment: So I can create a form post action/method into a HTML email that is received by an email client? Would there be any issues? What do you mean by it is uncacheable?

Comment: Both get and post can only be targetted as something that understands http requests - so a web server.  An email client could not be the target.

Comment: @grawity just wanted to follow up, I read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416753/can-i-put-both-get-and-post-url-link-in-an-email that implies that POST will not work. And I have my own question about this where I've followed your method, and for whatever reason the request still reads as GET and doesn't go through. There's a bounty on it, would really appreciate your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189818/button-to-in-email-not-posting